# How to display m:m relations in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm building blog nodejs api. I have tables such as Post, Category and PostCategory.

So, i want to query data from PostCategory.

```
const Post = sequelize.define('post', {
    id:  {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    content: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
    },

    photo: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
})


const Category = sequelize.define('category', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
    },

    label: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
})
```

And here is my associations:

```
const PostCategory = sequelize.define('postcategory', {
    postId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: Post,
            key: 'id',
        }
    },

    categoryId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: Category,
            key: 'id',
        }
    }
})

Post.belongsToMany(Category, { through: PostCategory })
Category.belongsToMany(Post, { through: PostCategory })
```

And question: "how to display to show post and with its categories?"
I've tried:

```
const posts = await PostCategory.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: Post
            }]
        }).then(post => response.send(post))
```

But taken the response: {"name":"SequelizeEagerLoadingError"}

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Post.findAll({ include: [{ model: Category }] })` to get all posts and their associated categories instead of using join table `PostCategory`.

Here is a working example using `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

const Post = sequelize.define('post', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  content: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false,
  },

  photo: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

const Category = sequelize.define('category', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },

  label: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

const PostCategory = sequelize.define('postcategory', {
  postId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: Post,
      key: 'id',
    },
  },

  categoryId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: Category,
      key: 'id',
    },
  },
});

(Post as any).belongsToMany(Category, { through: PostCategory });
(Category as any).belongsToMany(Post, { through: PostCategory });

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await (Post as any).bulkCreate(
      [
        { content: 'post 1', photo: 'photo 1', categories: [{ label: 1 }, { label: 2 }] },
        { content: 'post 2', photo: 'photo 2', categories: [{ label: 3 }, { label: 4 }] },
      ],
      { include: [Category] },
    );

    const posts = await (Post as any).findAll({
      include: [{ model: Category }],
      raw: true,
    });
    console.log(posts);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

Printed `posts`:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    content: 'post 1',
    photo: 'photo 1',
    'categories.id': 1,
    'categories.label': 1,
    'categories.postcategory.postId': 1,
    'categories.postcategory.categoryId': 1
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    content: 'post 1',
    photo: 'photo 1',
    'categories.id': 2,
    'categories.label': 2,
    'categories.postcategory.postId': 1,
    'categories.postcategory.categoryId': 2
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    content: 'post 2',
    photo: 'photo 2',
    'categories.id': 3,
    'categories.label': 3,
    'categories.postcategory.postId': 2,
    'categories.postcategory.categoryId': 3
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    content: 'post 2',
    photo: 'photo 2',
    'categories.id': 4,
    'categories.label': 4,
    'categories.postcategory.postId': 2,
    'categories.postcategory.categoryId': 4
  }
]
```

Data records in database:

```
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from post;
 id | content |  photo  
----+---------+---------
  1 | post 1  | photo 1
  2 | post 2  | photo 2
(2 rows)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from category;
 id | label 
----+-------
  1 |     1
  2 |     2
  3 |     3
  4 |     4
(4 rows)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from postcategory;
 postId | categoryId 
--------+------------
      1 |          1
      1 |          2
      2 |          3
      2 |          4
(4 rows)
```